# How to convert between color models

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I am very new to image processing. I have a PNG image (read using `ImageIO.read()`) that yields `BufferedImage.TYPE_CUSTOM` when I call `getType()` on it.

```
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new URL("file:/C:/samp1.png"));
int type =bi.getType(); //TYPE_CUSTOM for samp1.png
```

Now I would like to convert it to one of the following models:

1. TYPE_USHORT_GRAY
2. TYPE_3BYTE_BGR
3. TYPE_BYTE_GRAY
4. TYPE_INT_RGB
5. TYPE_INT_ARGB

The above needs to be done to process the image further using a library that recognises only the above types.

How do I convert from `TYPE_CUSTOM` color model to other models?

Any help/pointers would be much appreciated.
If there aren't any existing library to do this, any link/post to steps/algorithm would be great.

Comment: I am still looking for a "?" mark in your question, Sorry buddy could you please rephrase your question thanks

Comment: @Krio added the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
BufferedImage rgbImg = new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Comment: Doesn't this just create a new blank image? You and Eric seem to have chosen the same method, using the graphics object to redraw the image, even if it looks like you only wrote the first line of it. I'm convinced there's a faster way, perhaps buried in the AWT files or something you would need to implement yourself, converting the WritableRaster returned by getData(). (That is, unless drawImage takes these shortcuts as it is, but I doubt that.) Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
public static BufferedImage convert(BufferedImage src, int bufImgType) {
    BufferedImage img= new BufferedImage(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), bufImgType);
    Graphics2D g2d= img.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(src, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.dispose();
    return img;
}
```

Comment: this answer works the best, the answer marked as acceptable only creates a blank image. You still have to fill the data in it.